# Problems with meta tags with Next js

Tags: next.js, meta-tags, social-media

I am new in ***Next js*** and trying to write some ***dynamical open graph meta tags*** in my project about social media. The thing is, I am able to see all of meta tags in my inspector but when I am trying to find them in my sources code or in the facebook sharing debugger I can only see a few meta tags and they are not related with open graph ones.

The meta tags that I see in my sources or sharing debugger:

```
<head>
       <meta charSet="utf-8"/>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
       <meta name="next-head-count" content="2"/>
</head>
```

I create a custom Head with next/head, I have located this custom head in a layout, not in the ***_app.js*** file (but I tried to add it there, with no good results). I do not have no ***getServerSideProps*** function, and I do not know where to implement this function in my code. Any idea of what can be?

Answer (score 2):

> I do not have no getServerSideProps function, and I do not know where to implement this function in my code.

You can define `getServerSideProps` only on the page components(under the pages directory).

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering

There is a question, how do you retrieve the dynamic values of meta tags? If you fetch them on the client by using `useEffect`, the values of meta tags are undefined at the initial rendering.

If you need to fetch values from external data source, you should fetch them in `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` and pass them to the page props.

Comment: I am not using useEffect in the component of custom head, I am passing as a props from my layout, where I take the information from the redux state